# Checking for the matched product and category Id

Tags: magento-1.8

I am using below code to check and display products for certain allowed categories only in Magento admin panel product grid, but Magento returns with error

```
$collection->getSelect()->join(
                array('cp'=>'catalog_category_product'), 
                'main_table.entity_id = cp.product_id AND cp.category_id IN (' . $where . ')',
                array()
            );
```

I have tried using another table also

```
$collection->getSelect()->join(
                array('cpi' => Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getTableName('catalog/category_product')),
                'main_table.entity_id = cpi.product_id',
                array()
            );
```

May any body suggests the solution for the same

Comment: what's is the error? what is the final select(after the load)

Comment: Thanks guys solved the problem. replaced main_table alias with e and it works!

Comment: Please place your solution as a answer!